# Mapping font url to font name

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, puppeteer

How to get font-name based off font-url using puppeteer

I am using `Network.requestIntercepted` to get list of fonts that are being used on a given website. However, the response does not contain any information about the font family that is being used in the CSS.

Is there a way to get font-family name and the corresponding font url that is being used on the page?

```
  await client.on('Network.requestIntercepted', async e => {
    if (e.resourceType == "Font") {
      console.log(e)
      fontCollection.add(e.request.url)
    }
```

While the response contains font details, it does not contain the font-family name

```
{ interceptionId: 'interception-job-14.0',
  request:
   { url:
      'https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/lato/v15/S6uyw4BMUTPHjx4wWyWtFCc.ttf',
     method: 'GET',
     headers:
      { Origin: 'https://goldrate.com',
        'User-Agent':
         'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) HeadlessChrome/73.0.3679.0 Safari/537.36',
        Accept: '*/*',
        Referer:
         'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,100i,300,300i,400,400i,700,700i,900,900i' },
     initialPriority: 'VeryHigh',
     referrerPolicy: 'no-referrer-when-downgrade' },
  frameId: '4127ABB5A3E704843D0AB4756C7507E4',
  resourceType: 'Font',
  isNavigationRequest: false }
```

Comment: One option would be to parse the `Referer` and try to deduce the name of font-family via regex.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1. Guess the font from URL and/or HTTP headers
2. Download the font file and inspect it

#### Option 1: Guess the font from URL and HTTP headers

By looking at the request information, you can see the font name at two positions. First, in the URL and second in the Referer:

- URL

  > fonts.gstatic.com/s/**lato**/v15/S6uyw4BMUTPHjx4wWyWtFCc.ttf
- Referer:

  > fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=**Lato**:100,100i,300,300i,400,400i,700,700i,900,900i

From that information you can therefore find out which font is being used.

#### Option 2: Download the font file and inspect it

If the first option is not realiable enough (maybe you want to crawl other pages, too?), you can always download the file by using a tool like [node-fetch](https://github.com/bitinn/node-fetch) when intercepting the request
and then parse the meta information of the font file.

The library [fontkit](https://github.com/foliojs/fontkit) is able to parse a `ttf` file and read its [Metadata](https://github.com/foliojs/fontkit#metadata-properties) like `familyName` or `fullName`:

**Code sample**

```js
const fetch = require('node-fetch'); 
const fontkit = require('fontkit');
(async () => {
    const response = await fetch('https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/lato/v15/S6uyw4BMUTPHjx4wWyWtFCc.ttf');
    const buffer = await response.buffer();
    const font = fontkit.create(buffer);
    console.log(font.familyName); // "Lato"
    console.log(font.fullName);   // "Lato Regular"
})();
```

You could then do this inside your `Network.requestIntercepted` block to find out which font is being used.